# difference in Months between two dates using MS WORD

Tags: ms-word

I need to get the difference between two dates and I want it displayed in number of months(MS WORD), I am using this formula at the moment:

```
{QUOTE
{SET sy{ MERGEFIELD  CASS_CALCULATED_LAST_PMT_DATE \@ yyyy}}
{SET sm{ MERGEFIELD  CASS_CALCULATED_LAST_PMT_DATE \@ M}}
{SET sd{ MERGEFIELD  CASS_CALCULATED_LAST_PMT_DATE \@ d}}
{SET ey{ MERGEFIELD  LETTER_DATE \@ yyyy}}
{SET em{ MERGEFIELD  LETTER_DATE \@ M}}
{SET ed{ MERGEFIELD  LETTER_DATE \@ d}}
{SET md{=IF((em=2),28+(em=2)*((MOD(ey,4)=0)+(MOD(ey,400)=0)-(MOD(ey,100)=0)),31-((em=4)+(em=6)+(em=9)+(em=11)))}}
{Set Years{=ey-sy-(em<sm)-(em=sm)*(ed<sd)}}
{Set Months{=MOD(12+em-sm-(ed<sd),12) \# 0}}
{Set Days{=MOD(md+ed-sd,md) \# 0}}
"{Years} Year{IF{Years}= 1 "" s}, {Months} Month{IF{Months}= 1 "" s}, {Days} Day{IF{Days}= 1 "" s}."}
```

Right now im trying to calculate the difference between 01.10.2020 and 02.02.2021. the result given is:0 Years, 0 Months, 2 Days.

could you please let me know how can I adjust it so that it works and that it would display the difference only in months, leaving out years and days.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Delete:

```
{SET md{=IF((em=2),28+(em=2)*((MOD(ey,4)=0)+(MOD(ey,400)=0)-(MOD(ey,100)=0)),31-((em=4)+(em=6)+(em=9)+(em=11)))}}
```

Replace:

```
{Set Months{=MOD(12+em-sm-(ed<sd),12) \# 0}}
{Set Days{=MOD(md+ed-sd,md) \# 0}}
"{Years} Year{IF{Years}= 1 "" s}, {Months} Month{IF{Months}= 1 "" s}, {Days} Day{IF{Days}= 1 "" s}."}
```

with:

```
{Set Months{={=MOD(12+em-sm-(ed<sd),12)+Years*12} \# 0}}
"{Months} Month{IF{Months}= 1 "" s}"}
```

Comment: Somehow 'Replace:' in my draft disappeared. Fixed.

Comment: @macropod made the changes as you per your example, it does seem to work, however it gives back an answer of "0 months". do you have any Idea what could be the issue? when I tried it with my original formula it gave the answer of 0 Years 0 months and 2 days, basically it just counted the difference in days not taking into account years and months.

Comment: Well, '0 Years 0 months and 2 days' is '0 months'... That said, for me the same start & end dates, return '0 Years, 4 Months, 1 Day.' with the original field code, which suggests there's a problem in your implementation of the field code.

Comment: I have added my outcome as an answer as formating options are better there. The date fields are being recognized, so I am not sure where is the problem, I also have a working formula for the difference in days, but the months are not displaying correctly.

Comment: As I said, the field code works correctly for me - without and with the modification. I can only conclude that your implementation of the original field code is faulty. I suggest you *copy* the original field code from my tutorial (https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38719-microsoft-word-date-calculation-tutorial.html or http://www.gmayor.com/downloads.htm#Third_party) and start again. Note, too, that you can insert {SET StartDate {MERGEFIELD CASS_CALCULATED_LAST_PMT_DATE} and {SET EndDate {MERGEFIELD LETTER_DATE} fields (after 'QUOTE') and avoid the repeated mergefield references.

Answer (score 0):

@macropod, please see my outcome here:

126 – Difference in days between CASS_CALCULATED_LAST_PMT_DATE and LETTER_DATE

0  - Difference in months between CASS_CALCULATED_LAST_PMT_DATE and LETTER_DATE (orriginal formula)

0 Months (new formula as per your suggestion)

2020  - CASS_CALCULATED_LAST_PMT_DATE @ yyyy

10  - CASS_CALCULATED_LAST_PMT_DATE @ M

1  - CASS_CALCULATED_LAST_PMT_DATE @ d

2021  - LETTER_DATE @ yyyy

2  - LETTER_DATE @ M

4  - LETTER_DATE @ d